# Bootstrap carousel refuses to transition smoothly after css adjustments

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

For the last 3 hours I've been trying to make a simple adjustment to Bootstrap 3's carousel transitions.
I've tried changing the slide speed where this is the only thing that seems to have any effect:

```
.carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

but it hides the 'leaving' content too soon, and I have no clue what property to modify to fix that.

I've also tried changing it to a fade transition with

```
.carousel-fade .item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.carousel-fade .active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.carousel-fade .left {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

And just about every other snippet to do so that I've come across, but every single one always first removed the leaving content, showing a featureless background, before fading in the next. What am I missing? All I need is some plain CSS to override the existing transition details, but I don't know where to look any more.

Comment: You should probably reset the original transitions, see also: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/change-bootstraps-carousel-animantion/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think different aspects of bootstrap's carousel plugin give the effects you mention.

1. Active items have `display: block` while not active items have `display: none`

   This can be solved by giving all items `display: block` and then setting the `position` to `absolute` with `top: 0` and `left: 0`, resulting in the items overlapping. Setting `opacity: 0;` makes them invisible by default.

   Less:

   ```
   .carousel-inner > .item {
     opacity: 0;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
   }
   ```

   One problem of the `position: absolute` is that the container does not get a `height`. The preceding can be solved by setting the `position` of the first item to `relative` (it is add the right position already). In Less code, it is as follows:

   ```
   .carousel-inner > .item {
     :first-of-type {
       position:relative;
     } 
   }
   ```
2. Bootstrap uses `translate3d`s to change the position of the item in the space. You won't need these transformations, so reset them. Leveraging Less, code shown below:

   ```
   .carousel-inner > .item {
     transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
   }
   ```
3. The CSS transitions are triggered by adding and removing CSS classes with jQuery. The time between these class changes has been hardcoded in the carousel plugin code (`Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600`). So, after 600 ms, one item becomes active (having the .active class). That is the reason for the unexpected behavior if your css `transition-duration` is greater than 0.6 seconds.

The CSS class changes are as follows:

The active item has class `.active` -> `.active.left` -> none
The next item has no class -> `.next.left` -> `.active`

So the `.active.left` and `.next.left` are important (or `.prev.right` and `.active.right` when you slide backwards).

Because all images are already stacked, you can use the `z-index` property to make an image in the stack visible, because we can change the `opacity` at the same time. You can use the following Less code to fade in the next slide:

```
.carousel-inner {
  > .next.left {
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:2;
  }
  > .active.left {
    z-index:1;
  }
}
```

To make sure that the controls are visible as well, use:

```
.carousel-control {
  z-index:4;
}
```

Putting all together, see the results in [this demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbRzwL), which uses the following Less code:

```
.carousel-inner {
 > .item {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
  transition: none;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
  &:first-of-type {
    position:relative;
  } 
  }
 > .active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index:3;
}

 > .next.left,
 > .prev.right {
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  z-index:2;
  }                                                                                                             
 > .active.left,
 > .active.right {
  z-index:1;
  }
}
.carousel-control {
z-index:4;
}
```

The above code can be compiled with the [Less autoprefixer plugin](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) plugin into CSS with the following command:

```
lessc --autoprefix="Android 2.3,Android >= 4,Chrome >= 20,Firefox >= 24,Explorer >= 8,iOS >= 6,Opera >= 12,Safari >= 6' code.less
```

which outputs:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: none;
       -o-transition: none;
          transition: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
.carousel-inner > .item:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
          transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left,
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-control {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful solution! But... how can I increase the fade speed? Increasing the transition time it lost the smooth transition

Comment: Also, another issue of this solution: using the control prev/next it doesn't change the slides. How can solve it?

Comment: You should change the Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION in the plugin and the `transition-duration`. In the demo prev / next works??

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this and it was driving me insane - on Bootstrap's Introduction page, if you look under Components, it lists Carousel as one of the components requiring JS. I had to add their CSS stylesheet before all other stylesheets, then their Bootstrap / JS plugin bundle right before the closing body tag. Finally fixed the issue. I've linked them below in order, starting with the Introduction page.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/